# Count number of rows to a specific value (and count in reverse)

Tags: r, dataframe, counting

I have this data

```
data.frame(x1 = c(rep(0, 3), rep(1, 4), rep(0, 4)))
```

And I want to count in this way:

X2 column

[image]

Can anyone explain how can i do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option with `rle` :

```
df <- data.frame(x1 = c(rep(0, 3), rep(1, 4), rep(0, 4)))

df$x2 <- unlist(with(rle(df$x1), mapply(function(x, y) 
                if(x == 0) rev(-seq(y)) else seq(y) - 1, values, lengths)))
df

#   x1 x2
#1   0 -3
#2   0 -2
#3   0 -1
#4   1  0
#5   1  1
#6   1  2
#7   1  3
#8   0 -4
#9   0 -3
#10  0 -2
#11  0 -1
```

This can also be written with the help of `ave` :

```
df$x2 <- ave(df$x1, data.table::rleid(df$x1), FUN = function(x) 
              if(x[1] == 0) rev(-seq_along(x)) else seq_along(x) - 1)
```

The logic of both the code is the same. We create groups of consecutive 0 and 1 values, if the group value is 0 then create a sequence from 1 to length of the group, make it negative and reverse the values. If the group value is 1 create a sequence from 0 to length of the group - 1.

Answer (score 0):

We could use `rleid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, x2 := (seq_len(.N)-1) - c(0, .N)[(1 + all(!x1))], rleid(x1)]
```

-output

```
df1
#    x1 x2
# 1:  0 -3
# 2:  0 -2
# 3:  0 -1
# 4:  1  0
# 5:  1  1
# 6:  1  2
# 7:  1  3
# 8:  0 -4
# 9:  0 -3
#10:  0 -2
#11:  0 -1
```